# How to disable and enable jetty request log dynamically?

Tags: java, logging, request, jetty

How to disable and enable jetty request log dynamically in a web project?I want to disable the request log when the system resource is pretty low which may save the world.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`Slf4jRequestLog`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Slf4jRequestLog.html) implementation for Request Logging and simply enable/disable the selected Slf4j implementation using the techniques that the implementation provides.

You cannot rely on the behaviors of the default implementation in your use case.